# Where can I find example of good webMathematica programming?

Tags: webmathematica

Just now I started to work on webMathematica. I surprised that I can't do whatever I do with mathematica. Can any one suggest me where I can get good practice on webMathematica.

Comment: Maybe [here](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/examples/examples.html) ?

Comment: Try a search first before posting a question.  Answer here.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice

Comment: Are you looking for examples outside of the ones at WolframResearch's website? I'm not sure there are instructive examples elsewhere. You could find some webpages made with WebMathematica, but you would have to look into the raw html yourself.

Comment: @R Hall The link you sent is for Mathematica not for webMathematica

Comment: @RHall I'm afraid I have to agree with Niren here

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I flagged it as duplicate (it was declined) as the accepted answer includes [a reference to webmathematica examples](http://www.mathematica-users.org/webMathematica/). I agree it's marginal but I thought the link may have been added after this question was asked

Comment: @gpap I noticed that link, but since RHall could have just as well (or better) provided it directly instead of buried in a long page of largely irrelevant stuff my conclusion was that he was probably confused by the title which is very similar to that of the other question. It is clearly not a duplicate of that question.